# Random choice in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to choose something from a list randomly, however, how do i make it so it cant choose it again if called?

This for a card game and i want to choose a value of suit to show up in the top left and bottom right corner, but only one value per card of that suit should be chosen

```
card_value = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J','10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
card_value = choice(card_value)
```

i want to choose a value of suit to show up in the top left and bottom right corner, but only one value per card of that suit should be chosen

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, your code cannot do anything as you are reassigning the value `card_value`

However, you can perform the desired output with two methods from random

```
from random import choice, shuffle

choices = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J','10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']

shuffle(choices)

def pick_a_card(l):
    return l.pop()

card_value = pick_a_card(choices)
print(card_value)
card_value = pick_a_card(choices)
print(card_value)
print(choices)


# Or use choice and remove

def pick_a_card(l):
    card = choice(l)
    l.remove(card)
    return card

choices = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J','10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']


card_value = pick_a_card(choices)
print(card_value)
card_value = pick_a_card(choices)
print(card_value)
print(choices)
```

`shuffle` shuffles the list, and you just need to perform a `pop`

`choice` takes a random element, and you just have to reove it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt python `random` library to do it.You should read more about the options in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) where you can give the probability to pick the option and many more features

```
import random

card_value = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J','10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
print(random.choice(card_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

items = ['here', 'are', 'some', 'strings', 'of',
         'which', 'we', 'will', 'select', 'one']

rand_item = items[random.randrange(len(items))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that samples a value from `card_value`, and removes it from it:

```
def pick_a_card(deck):
    import numpy as np

    # index of the card to pick
    i = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = len(deck)-1)

    # value of the card picked
    pick = deck[i]

    # remove only that card from the deck
    del deck[i]

    # the returns the card picked and the deck without it
    return pick, deck
```

You can then call:

```
choice, card_value = pick_a_card(card_value)
```

If this doesn't fit to your problem let me know.

Comment: I am not sure adding a heavy dependency is the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using the `choice` function you can get a random integer as index and use `pop()` on the list:

```py
import random

card_value = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J','10', '9', '8', '7',
              '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
random_card = card_value.pop(random.randint(0, len(card_value)-1))
```

Note however, this will throw a `ValueError` if the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list containing all the cards etc. 'kh' = King of hearts and so on. Then do like this and move the picked cards to another array so they can not be picked from the deck.

```
import random
def random_card():
    # Clubs = c, Spades = s, Hearts = h, Diamonds = d
    deck = ['kc', 'ks', 'kh', 'kd', 'qc']
    picked_cards = []
    selected_card = random.choice(deck)
    print('selected card ' + selected_card)
    picked_cards.append(selected_card)
    deck.pop(deck.index(selected_card))
```